# Norm group of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[4]{\zeta_{p-1}p})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $p \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ be a prime, and let $\zeta_{p-1}$ be a primitive $(p-1)^\mathrm{st}$ root of unity in the $p$-adic number $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $K$ be the extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[4]{\zeta_{p-1}p})$. Formally, we define $K$ to be the quotient ring.
$$
K = \frac{\mathbb{Q}_p[X]}{(X^4 - \zeta_{p-1}p)}.
$$
I would like to compute the norm group
$$
\operatorname{Nm}(K^\times) = \{N_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(\alpha) : \alpha \in K\}.
$$

**My Attempt**

Clearly $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 4} \subseteq \operatorname{Nm}(K^\times)$, and we also have
$$
N_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(\sqrt[4]{\zeta_{p-1}p}) = - \zeta_{p-1}p,
$$
so it follows that
$$
\{u(-\zeta_{p-1})^kp^k : u \in \mathcal{O}_K^{\times 4}, k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \operatorname{Nm}(K^\times).
$$
Now, if $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ were an abelian extension, then we would be done, because local class field theory tells us that $[\mathbb{Q}_p^\times : \operatorname{Nm}(K^\times)] = 4$, and the subgroup $\{u(-\zeta_{p-1})^kp^k : u \in \mathcal{O}_K^{\times 4}, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ has index $4$.

However, for $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, the extension is not Galois and its Galois closure has Galois group $D_8$ (based on looking at examples in the LMFDB), which obviously is not abelian. Is there still some similar way to conclude the argument?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is given by Theorem III.3.5 of [Milne's Class Field Theory notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf), which states that for a finite extension $L/K$ of local fields, we have
$$
N_{L/K}(L^\times) = N_{E/K}(E^\times),
$$
where $E$ is the largest abelian extension of $K$ contained in $L$. Therefore in my concrete case, we would have $E = \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{\zeta_{p-1}p})$, so the norm group we are looking for is
$$
\{u(-\zeta_{p-1}p)^k : u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times 2}, k \in \mathbb{Z}\},
$$
which is of index $2$.